# How do I put the state of my tun interface to up? My tun interface is not receiving packets

Tags: networking, virtualization, tunnel, network-interface

Here are my command when I set up the interface:

```
 ip tuntap add dev router0 mod tun
 ip addr add 10.0.0.138/24 dev router0
 ip link set dev router0 up
```

Here is the output of ip addr show dev router0

```
8: router0: <NO-CARRIER,POINTOPOINT,MULTICAST,NOARP,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 500
    link/none 
    inet 10.0.0.138/24 scope global router0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

As you see, the state says down despite me using  `ip link set dev router0 up`.

When I try to ping 10.0.0.138 listen on the interface using tshark via `sudo tshark -i router0`, nothing happens.

Here is my `ping 10.0.0.138` output:

```
PING 10.0.0.138 (10.0.0.138) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.0.138: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.063 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.0.138: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.058 ms
```

Here is my sudo tshark -i router0 output:

```
Capturing on 'router0'
```

Nothing is coming through

What is the problem?

Comment: So what are you actually trying to achieve? A TUN interface does nothing on its own. You *must* have software that does something with it.

Comment: For a project, I am creating a router that has a routing table and reads/writes to interfaces. I will be using tun interfaces as my router's interfaces to receive/send packets from.